# CSS: Fit image with % w/h in div with % width

Tags: css, image

I have an image that I want to scale to 50% w+h but need it to fit in a div that has a width set to 25%. I keep getting a distorted image with a height set to 50% but the width set to 25%.

[image]

I'm using this css:

```
.pb_benefits_img_wrapper {
                height: 100%; 
                width:25%;
                float:left; 
                text-align:right; 
                padding-right: 15px; 
                padding-top: 10px;
                border:1px solid red;

            }

            .pb_benefits_img_wrapper > img { 
                width: 50%;
                min-height: 50%;
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You set image to be minimum 50% of height. Since your container is very high, that's where your distortion comes from. Set `max-height` and `max-width` instead and make sure you have big enough images to fill at-least 50%

Comment: Does the parent box (img_wrapper) need to be 100%? this is causing the container to be far larger than your intended image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say it's ideal but hope below code will help you.

```
<style>
    img.image{
        visibility:hidden;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
    }
    .imageContainer{
        background-image:url("backgroundImage.webp");
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:50%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        width:25%;
        display:inline-block;
    }
</style>

<div class="imageContainer"><img class="image" src="backgroundImage.webp" alt="sample image" /> </div>
```

If the image's served is a dynamic one then.Slight change will be the way the image is served.

Comment: ha, that's exactly what I did (kind of). Just trying to get it to stop resizing when ti reaches a certain width (original img is 303x303, want it to stop when the image is 1/4 (78px roughly).